# Elastic Search filter query for null values

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

### **I am trying to write a query where it searches in elastic that if fields is null then filter it out. In my case if both battery temperature and temperature value is null then remove it from the bucket, if one value is null then no need to filter.**

Above query is used and in some cases both temperature and battery values are coming null which I need to remove from the buckets.

```json
GET ts-history*/_search/?pretty
{
  "aggs": {
    "timestamp": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "1s",
        "time_zone": "America/New_York",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "temperature75cea6bd-21bb-4794-8314-0291a7c9ad71": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "temperature"
          }
        },
        "heater_temperature75cea6bd-21bb-4794-8314-0291a7c9ad71": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "battery_temperature"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "stored_fields": ["*"],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": 1644225612000,
              "lte": 1644315612000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "asset_id.keyword": {
              "query": "75cea6bd-21bb-4794-8314-0291a7c9ad71"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

query should get asset 1 and 3 but in my case i am getting asset 2 which i need to filter.

```
AssetId Timestamp                       temperature   battery_temperature
1      2022-02-07T06:31:37.000-05:00   10             null
2      2022-02-07T06:35:37.000-05:00   null           null
3      2022-02-07T06:40:37.000-05:00   null           20
```

Comment: Please add your sample document.

Comment: @SagarPatel bro sample dataset added.

Comment: i was asking for elastic sample document. anyway i have post answer so please check and accept / up vote if helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need to get document if atleast one field available then you can use should clause with [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html).

Below is query for your requirement:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "temperature"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "battery_temperature"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Sample document which is in index:

```json
{
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "nullcheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "w9V43X4BGC8jFmD-T06n",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "temperature" : 10,
          "battery_temperature" : 10
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "nullcheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "xNV43X4BGC8jFmD-Z06W",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "temperature" : null,
          "battery_temperature" : 10
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "nullcheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "xdV43X4BGC8jFmD-hk4n",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "temperature" : null,
          "battery_temperature" : null
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Response for above query:

```json
{
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "nullcheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "w9V43X4BGC8jFmD-T06n",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "temperature" : 10,
          "battery_temperature" : 10
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "nullcheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "xNV43X4BGC8jFmD-Z06W",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "temperature" : null,
          "battery_temperature" : 10
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The desired result achieve after adding   "minimum_should_match" : 1 in your query Thankyou @sagarPatel

Comment: "minimum_should_match" : 1 is default value for should cluase, do you have other should clause as well ?

Comment: Due to must clause the minimum_should_match" is 0.if the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value is 0.

Comment: got it. i thought you are trying query with only should clause. its great that my answer help you. please upvote as well if you feel answer is useful.

Comment: Thankyou you so much buddy.